# How to import a table which is different postgres server in python?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Assume that I have two Postgresql servers running, On server-1 I have a table called "employee_info", I want to use this table in python flask code through SQL alchemy, right now I have connected to "server-2" from my application.

How can use the "employee_info" from server-1 in my current code?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using [Multiple Databases with Binds](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/binds/) (from the flask-sqlalchemy documentation).